# exec () php, sh script runs partially

Tags: php, exec

sorry for bad english..

i have php file like this:

```
<?php

exec(`sh /tmp/script.sh`); 

echo "Work!";
?>
```

and this is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

url="http://someweb.com/get.php?user=user&pass=pass";

wget -O /tmp/file.txt $url

sed -i 's/#Test_file/Ok_Test_file/' /tmp/file.txt

cp /tmp/file.txt /var/www/_client/personale/file.txt
```

Now when load file.php to the browser, the script works ,but only commands
wget and sed are performed , except cp which doesn't work..does not copy the file!
If i run the script to terminal manually (Debian 8) all cmd are executed...
Where is the problem?
Thanks.
Joele

Comment: Hi Joele, please learn how to format your question so it's easier to read

Comment: Joele, I can see you're struggling to edit your question properly. You can add code sections by putting four spaces before each line of code.

Comment: What does `ls -lah /var/www/_client/personale` show?
What does `id` show?

Comment: ls -lah /var/www/_client/personale

    drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4,0K dic 18 18:27 .
    drwxr-xr-x 15 root root 4,0K dic 17 23:28 ..
    drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4,0K dic 18 18:23 speed

Answer (score 0):

PHP likely does not have permission to execute the command. Try using `sudo` to execute the command.